# Combination with replacement where each item selected at least once

Tags: combinatorics

If I select $K$ items with replacement from $N$, then the number of combinations is
$$
C_r(N,K) = C(N+K-1,K).
$$
I would like to work out what is the number of combinations where each item has been selected at least once.

Comment: For Stars and Bars theory, see 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  As you indicated, the number of solutions to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$$ is $~\displaystyle \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}.~$ To handle changing the constraint to $~x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}},~$ simply set $~y_i = x_i - 1 \implies$ $$y_1 + \cdots + y_k = n-k ~: ~y_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.